# Как скомбинировать нажатия "Ctrl" и "+"?

Tags: java, клавиатура

Мне нужно чтоб браузер изменил свои масштаб ( zoom in/out ), пытаюсь это организовать следующими метода, но ни один из них не работает. Прошу помогите.

```
new Key(RemoteIME.mService, event.getAction(), KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CTRL_LEFT & KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ZOOM_IN);

new Key(RemoteIME.mService, event.getAction(), KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CTRL_LEFT & KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PLUS);
```